# EditText long press menu

Tags: android

I have EditText. Long press on digits keys (on Remove control) shows dialog (see below). The same long press on letter do nothing. Is it possible do not show this dialog?

[image: dialog]

Comment: Not all input method editors will offer this dialog, and AFAIK there is no way to control whether or not it will appear for input method editors that do offer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid showing this menu you have to do a small trick:

```
static {
    try {
        Field field = QwertyKeyListener.class.getDeclaredField("PICKER_SETS");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        ((SparseArray) field.get(null)).clear();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It will avoid any kind of pick dialogs in all views in your app.